# Add value from column based on other column through loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following data frame:

```
ViewKey     Table_Name
car         A
car         B
NaN         C
ball        D
ball        E
```

and the following sentences:

```
contains_car = " SELECT \n keys \n FROM *letter here*  \n LEFT JOIN "
contains_ball = " SELECT \n keys \n FROM *letter here*  \n RIGHT JOIN "
contains_NaN = " SELECT \n keys \n FROM *letter here*  \n ALL"
```

I want to `"print"` with the following idea:

If my raw contains `car` print `contains_car` value but instead of `*letter here*` write corresponding value of column `Table_name`:

```
# as it related to "car" value in the column it printed contains_car value. 
# And at the same time instead of *letter here* wrote A because for the first car value A is corresponding:


SELECT  
 keys 
 FROM A
 LEFT JOIN


 SELECT 
 keys 
 FROM B 
 LEFT JOIN

 SELECT 
 keys 
 FROM C
 ALL

 SELECT 
 keys 
 FROM D 
 RIGHT JOIN

 SELECT 
 keys 
 FROM E 
 RIGHT JOIN
```

I tried:

```
for i in df['ViewKey'].fillna("0"):
    if 'car' in i:
        print(contains_car)
    elif 'ball' in i:
        print(contains_ball)
    elif '0' in i:
        print(contains_NaN)
```

IDK where to put if conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
df = df.fillna("0")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if "car" in row['ViewKey']:
        print(contains_car.replace("*letter here*", row['Table_Name']))
    if "ball" in row['ViewKey']:
        print(contains_ball.replace("*letter here*", row['Table_Name']))
    if "0" in row['ViewKey']:
        print(contains_NaN.replace("*letter here*", row['Table_Name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can get your output without if-statements. If your dataframe name is `df`:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print("SELECT \n keys \n FROM {0} \n {1}\n".format(row['Table_Name'], row['ViewKey']))
```

Comment: A apologize for my question. I have changed it. Sorry for the time you spent

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
   print("SELECT \n keys \n FROM {} \n {} \n".format(row['Table_Name'], row['ViewKey']))
```

Above is the code to simply print your requirement. If you want to do via loop, as you specified in the problem, then a problem that will arise is that `df['Table_Name'][df['ViewKey'] == 'car']` will output both 'A' and 'B', while only 1 is required at a time for printing. This will require 5 different ifs, which is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: A apologize for my question. I have changed it. Sorry for the time you spent

Comment: Its alright @EndryCrue. Hope it helps some other solution seekers